# compare element position from first array with number from second one

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to compare the two arrays, more specifically to do something with values from the first one whose positions matches the numbers from second one.

```
var valuesList = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'],
    positionNumberList = [0, 2, 4];
```

from above arrays value1 should be eq to 0 from second one, value3 = 2 .etc

I started with the code below but can not get the position of the values from the first array.

```
for(j=0; j < valuesList.length; j++){

   for(k=0; k < positionNumberList.length; k++){
       //find matching values from first array                     
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the final array you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you only need a single loop to iterate through the `positionNumberList` array, and then access the items in `valuesList` with the given indexes, like this:

```js
var valuesList = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'];
var positionNumberList = [0, 2, 4];

positionNumberList.forEach(function(index) {
  var value = valuesList[index];

  console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions is use `map()` method which applies a provided callback function for every item from `array`.

```js
var valuesList = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'],
 positionNumberList = [0, 2, 4];

console.log(positionNumberList.map(function(item) {
  return valuesList[item];
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
var valuesList = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5'],
    positionNumberList = [0, 2, 4];


if(positionNumberList.length < valuesList.length){
     for(var i=0; i < positionNumberList.length; i++){
         console.log(positionNumberList[i],valuesList[i])
     }
}
else{
    for(var i=0; i < valuesList.length; i++){
         console.log(valuesList[i],positionNumberList[i])
     }
}
```

#### https://jsfiddle.net/xrjjxmbn/